# What is the correct location to create a new WINEPREFIX?

Tags: debian, wine

I have a copy of WINE installed on a Debian Server. And I have now set up my first application.

The `.exe` is in `/home/user/appDir/appName.exe`

I have set up a `.desktop` file containing:

```
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/user/.wine" wine /home/user/appDir/appName.exe
```

This all works fine.

I now need a second copy of my application, so I will need a new **WINEPREFIX**.

Should I create the prefix as `/home/user/.wine2`, and put the second copy of the application as `/home/user/appDir2/appName.exe` ?

I'm just wondering because I notice that Firefox is also installed and seems to have it's own **WINEPREFIX** in `home/user/.local/share/wineprefixes/firefox`

And all the files are installed under `/home/user/.local/share/wineprefixes/firefox/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox`

Is either of these considered right / wrong? will one or the other come back to bite me later on (bearing in mind I may have 4 / 5 copies of my application to set up.